# any way to access data "loaded" via <script type=plaintext>

Tags: javascript, firefox

Im trying to load some code from an external domian with js. with script tags the browser is (according to firebug) loading the file. This is the code:

```
$('<script
type="plaintext"src="http://www.google.de"></sc'+'ript>').appendTo('body');
```

You cann see after loading the content of the file in this case an html document in firebug but is there any way to access this data for example with js?

Comment: can u explain your question a bit more? It isn't proper afaik

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think data loaded this way can be accessed. And even if it could, the Same Origin Policy would apply. Interested to see whether anything comes up

Comment: is it possible to access the Browserlayer one which firebug is working on without use of an addon?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  It would be possible if the *src* were on the same domain, by using *XMLHttpRequest* instead.

As a side note, *type* should be `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get `type` and `src` work together in a script!

It is what [WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/faq#what-is-the-whatwg) has stated [about type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#data-block) when set to anything else than Javascript:

> Setting the attribute to any other value means that the script is a
>   data block, which is not processed. None of the script attributes
>   (except type itself) have any effect on data blocks.

Data block is pretty useless without src - object or Blob is MUCH better. Loading something else than Javascript is not possible to access. Mime-types has no practical meaning for  except the multityde of mimes to load `.js` (and for except Web Extension writers possibly).